# How to redirect .ASPX pages to .NET Core Razor page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

We are moving a big asp.net web site to .NET Core Razor pages site. All over the internet there are links that point to our site and we want those links to work after our migration. We will kept the same url format, but without the extension .aspx.

Summary, we want our old url:

**example.com/item.aspx** be handle by .net core razor page, as

**example.com/item**

Comment: One option is to create a middleware handler. See https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Apr/18/Creating-a-generic-Markdown-Page-Handler-using-ASPNET-Core-Middleware where he handles .md files with URLs without the extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware) to remove the ".aspx" extensions.

Check the following code: Use **AddRedirect** to create a rule for rewriting URLs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //using Regex match the .aspx extension and remove it.
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirect(@"(\w*)(.aspx)", "$1");
        app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages(); 
        });
    }
```

Then, the screenshot like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ZhiLv, I will only add that I modify a bit the regEx to allow deeper URL's. like example.com/dictionary/the-item.aspx                                                                                 .                                                                                                                                          var options = new RewriteOptions()
                    .AddRedirect(@"(\w*\/?[\w*\-*]*)(.aspx)", "$1",301);